# Как исправить ошибку при создании приложения в django?

Tags: python, django

Я хотел создать приложение, добавил в файл urls строку    `path('webexample/', include('webexample.urls'))` и в консоле написал `python manage.py startapp webexemple`но консоль выдала

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\Влад\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webexempledjango'
```

как исправить ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webexempledjango'` ?

Вот файл urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('webexample/', include('webexample.urls'))
]
```

Comment: а вы добавили его в `INSTALLED_APPS` в файле `settings.py`? ну и `webexempledjango` не равно `webexample`

Comment: Да, добавил 

`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'webexemple'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]`

Comment: Но какая разницы между `webexempledjango` и `webexemple` ?

Comment: Никакой, но нужно указать именно то имя которое вы указали при создании апликейшена. Проверьте файлы `apps.py` и `manage.py` - нет ли там `webexempledjango`?

Comment: В INSTALLED_APPS просто забыта запятая. Так что вопрос закрыть как опечатку

Comment: а чехарда с буквой (exemple/example) так и задумывалась?

Answer (score 2):

Сначала вам необходимо создать приложение, а уже потом добавлять пути в urls.py

Django выдает вам ошибку, потому что вы написали путь к приложению которого не существует.

В вашем случае, алгоритм действий такой:

1. Создайте приложение: `python manage.py startapp webexemple`
2. Добавьте приложение в settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS = ['webexemple']`, но правильнее будет `INSTALLED_APPS = ['webexemple.apps.WebexampleConfig']` (проверьте правильное написание в файле apps.py вашего приложения)
3. Создайте файл urls.py в приложении webexample
4. Добавьте путь в корневой urls.py `path('webexample/', include('webexample.urls'))`